# Using pandas style to give colors to some rows with a specific condition

Tags: excel, pandas, pandas-styles

This is the output of  pandas in excel format:

```
Id      comments     number
1       so bad        1
1       so far        2
2       always        3
2       very good     4
3       very bad      5
3       very nice     6
3       so far        7
4       very far      8
4       very close    9
4       busy          10
```

I want to use pandas to give a color (for example: gray color) to rows that their value for `Id column` is even. For example rows 3 and 4 have even `Id` numbers, but rows 5, 6 and 7 have odd `Id` numbers. Is there any possible way to use pandas to do it?

Comment: Have you checked the [documentation page](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html)?

Comment: @Nikos Tavoularis yes,  I read pandas style: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html,  but I do not know how to write a code for something I need.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the documentation http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html what you basically want to do is write a style function and `apply` it to the style object.

```
def _color_if_even(s):
    return ['background-color: grey' if val % 2 == 0 else '' for val in s]
```

and call it on my Styler object, i.e.,

```
df.style.apply(_color_if_even, subset=['id'])
```

Comment: thank you, it does not work. I mean after I create excel sheet from the data frame, the excel sheet has no color. I wrote this way: df2=df.style.apply(_color_if_even, subset=['id']), and then "df2.to_excel ("/Users/mzi/Desktop/lexa.xlsx"). But there is the following error: "AttributeError: 'Styler' object has no attribute 'to_excel'"

Comment: you are no longer dealing with a dataframe, but a Styler object. only dataframes have the property to_excel.

Comment: if you wish to apply conditional formatting to an excel document with python you should be using xlsxwriter, not pandas. http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_conditional_formats.html